# How to count how many characters in text node are actually displayed on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's suppose I read the contents of a text node like so:

```
s = current_node.getSelection().anchorNode.nodeValue;
```

What is the best way to count how many characters are displayed on the webpage due to this one node? I know that for example `&nbsp;` would be displayed as a literal string so no need to look for these. Is all I need to do then to count several spaces in a row as one character? Is there anything else I need to look out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask the browser for the text version of what's in the node like this:

```
var node = current_node.getSelection().anchorNode;
var text = node.textContent || node.innerText;
var length = text.length;
```

This will have already converted entities to their regular characters and will not include any HTML tags.  Multiple spaces will come out as multiple spaces though - that's just how this function in the browser works.  If you were pretty sure that there were no multiple `&nbsp;` sequences in the HTML, you could collapse the multiple spaces like this:

```
var node = current_node.getSelection().anchorNode;
var text = node.textContent || node.innerText;
text = text.replace(/ +/g, " ");
var length = text.length;
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/FpsGq/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how literally you mean to define "displayed on the webpage".  If the characters overflow a container with overflow: hidden, they won't be displayed on the webpage (due to their being hidden by a CSS rule).

Besides that, condensing a series of white spaces, ignoring escaped newlines and carriage returns (if that applies, like in <pre></pre>), and condensing escaped characters should be all you need.  I can't think of any other edge cases at least.